# Invoke-AzureRMVMRunCommand for Windows VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I need to help with command `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`

Microsoft said

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand 
    -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' 
    -Name 'vmname' 
    -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' 
    -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1' 
    -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

But I cannot find information how to catch variables in sample.ps1 ?

For Example I have script `script.ps1`

```
$domainName = corp.contoso.com
nvoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -Name 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1' -Parameter @{"MyDomainName"= "$domainName"}
```

and now I have a script sample.ps1

```
Install-ADDSForest -DomainName $MyDomainName -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $VMLocalAdminPassword -InstallDNS -Force
```

How can I define or pass variable `$MyDomainName` from script.ps1 to sample.ps1??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a parameter in the script and use it

```
Param(
    [string]$domainName
)
Install-ADDSForest -DomainName $domainName -InstallDNS -Force`
    -SafeModeAdministratorPassword $VMLocalAdminPassword
```

you would need to do the same for vmlocaladminpassword, i suppose

Comment: yeah, but I need it for automatization to define parameters only once in first script :/

Comment: not sure i understand what you dont like about this solution